# How do you properly promisify request?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Bluebird promisifaction is a little magic, and `request` is quite a mess (it's a function which behaves as an object with methods).

The specific scenario is quite simple: I have a request instance with cookies enabled, via a cookie jar (not using `request`'s global cookie handler). How can I effectively promisify it, and all of the methods it supports?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to:

- call `request(url)` -> Promise
- call `request.getAsync(url)` -> Promise
- call `request.postAsync(url, {})` -> Promise

It seems as though `Promise.promisifyAll(request)` is ineffective (as I'm getting "postAsync is not defined").

Comment: Full disclosure, I'm the author: [http-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-as-promised).

Comment: @idbehold you only have to disclose things if you're going to say something about them :P

Comment: This isn't trivial, please consider opening an issue at the issue tracker.

Comment: Isn't `request(...)` same as `request.get(...)`? Why do you need both?

Comment: @Esailija I guess it is, but it's mainly to avoid confusion. I guess the point is that all of the API is promisified, and I don't have a callback left hanging because I didn't realize I need it. Strictly speaking, yes. One of the two is optional.

Comment: @SecondRikudo if your module is just going to make request its API directly what is the point of using your module? I thought you are only using request internally and export your own wrapper that fixes these issues with request promisification.

Comment: @Esailija that's exactly the case. Right now I have a half-assed solution of using `Promise.fromNode()` to directly promisify the functions I need, and delegate the facade container methods to them. It's ugly, but it works. However, what makes `request` so special that `promisifyAll` has so much trouble with it?

Comment: @SecondRikudo when you `promisifyAll` it adds the methods on the request object (which is a function) this works just fine when you call the methods. However, the `request` function's function code is still normal, to promisify that you need to call normal `promisify` but it returns a new function object that doesn't copy properties over. Maybe if it copied custom properties over it would work, cannot test right now.

Comment: @SecondRikudo my point is that you can just `promisifyAll` and then in your exported function just delegate to `request.getAsync` and just don't use `request` module as a function. I recommend clearing the module cache so that when someone requires `"request"` somewhere else, it wouldn't have the Async methods on it.

Comment: @Esailija That might indeed work. But it still smells like a limitation of either library.

Comment: @SecondRikudo yes but I can't see why copying couldn't work so it will be likely fixed in a release tonight

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The following should work:

```
var request = Promise.promisify(require("request"));
Promise.promisifyAll(request);
```

Note that this means that `request` is not a free function since promisification works with prototype methods since the `this` isn't known in advance. It will only work in newer versions of bluebird. Repeat it when you need to when forking the request object for cookies.

---

If you're using Bluebird v3, you'll want to use the `multiArgs` option:

```
var request = Promise.promisify(require("request"), {multiArgs: true});
Promise.promisifyAll(request, {multiArgs: true})
```

This is because the callback for request is `(err, response, body)`: the default behavior of Bluebird v3 is to only take the first success value argument (i.e. `response`) and to ignore the others (i.e. `body`).

Comment: How does that work with `request`'s cookies? Because as far as I can tell, it creates a new instance of `request` with a cookie jar in it

Comment: @SecondRikudo it now works in new bluebird. Please check it out :)

Comment: when you say "newer versions", which versions specifically?

Comment: What does Bluebird's promisification do with the `response` and `body` arguments sent to the `request.get()` callback?  Is it ignoring the body and only using the `response` argument as the resolved value of the promise?

Comment: @Retsam that's just `{multiArgs: true}`, it's part of the answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yeah, I edited that into the answer after making my comment and looking into it more. (I should edit or delete my comment, I guess)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum could you expand on the concept of a "free function" and its promisification? I don't see many examples of this particular concept anywhere else. Thanks.

Answer (score 33):

you can use the [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) module.

> The world-famous HTTP client "Request" now Promises/A+ compliant.
>   Powered by Bluebird.

Install the module and you can use request in promise style.

```
npm install request-promise
```

Comment: nit: does not have the .tapCatch or other bluebird methods

Comment: It uses not the newest version of bluebird

Answer (score 12):

Note that you don't need the third callback parameter, `body`. It is also present on the `response` parameter. If you [check the source](https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/request.js#L1154) you can see that `body` is just a convenience for `response.body`. They are guaranteed to always be the same.

This means that simple promisification as described in other answers on this page is enough to get all response data.

```
const request = require('request')
const { promisify } = require('util')
const rp = promisify(request)

rp('https://example.com').then(({body, statusCode}) => ...)
```

This is only true of the `response` passed to the callback/promise. The `response` object passed to the response *event* is a standard `http.IncomingMessage` and as such has no `body` property.

Answer (score 9):

I give an example, by `util` base on **Node.js v11.10.0**

```
import { get, post } from "request";
import { promisify } from "util";

const [getAsync, postAsync] = [get, post].map(promisify);


getAsync("http://stackoverflow.com")
    .then(({statusCode, body}) => { 
       //do something 
     });
```

Or, equivalently using `async/await`:

```
const foo = async () => {
    const {statusCode, body} = await getAsync("http://stackoverflow.com")
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Note that the original question is about the `request` object specifically, not any of its methods, those are (relatively) easy.