# How to code with Promise from async.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async.js

**Background**

I usually write node.js script based on async.js to control the work flow. Sometimes I found that based on async.js, the code seems still a 'hell'. With multiple nest the code is not readable and tricky to maintain. I did some search here and found some useful resources - but most of them are general concepts. So I am going to ask a question. Any feedback would be appreciated.

**My common code**

```
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6];
var url = 'http://www.google.com';
async.mapLimit(array, 3, function(number, callback) {
       request(url + number, function(error, res, body){
                  //do sth
                 callback();
       });
}, function(err){//do nothing});
```

**Question**

So this time I want to replace this kind of code by Promise. Could you please help? If the question is duplicated, please suggest some useful resource url. Thanks!

Comment: Where is `url` defined? Do you want to process only first three elements in `array` array?

Comment: @guest271314 Hey, thanks for your attention. Url can be any string, it's not important here. For your second question, do you really know about async.js?

Comment: You can use `Promise` and `Promise.all()` method to resolve this issue

Comment: Have not tried `.mapLimit` method. Is expected result for first three elements of `array` to be processed?

Comment: `Promise.all` is not the answer — it runs all the requests right away. `.mapLimit` runs at most 3 at the time.

Comment: can you describe better what you want to accomplish with this code? It seems like you are calling http://www.google.com1, http://www.google.com2, http://www.google.com3 and then expect to do something on success. As suggested by abdulbarik, you can achieve this easily and natively with Promise.all

Comment: Hey guys. mapLimit doesn't mean only run the first three items. As @elmigranto tells, it runs at most 3 at the time, but finally will run all 6 items

Comment: @J.Lyu you either write your own concurrency limiting, or use alternative Promise implementation like Bluebird, it has concurrency option. With HTTP requests to same URL you can use node's Agent class to limit number of concurrent requests to the same host.

Comment: @elmigranto Thanks. I will try.  Let me check more answers and work out my own solution.

Comment: I would advise you to consider using Bluebird powered [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) or native ES6 promises powered [request-promise-native](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to [Promisify `request`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308131/how-do-you-properly-promisify-request), which can be done with native promises, but since you're using NodeJS, it would be preferable if you used the Bluebird promise library, which is almost strictly superior to the native implementation.

Then you can do:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const requestAsync = Promise.promisify(request); // This is what bluebird saves you
// requestAsync returns a promise instead of accepting a callback.

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const requestSingle = number => requestAsync(`${url}${number}`);

Promise.map(array, requestSingle, {concurrency: 3});
```

Note that `Promise.map()` is a Bluebird functionality, and not native.

The closest you can easily get with native is:

```
const arrayOfRequestPromises = array.map(requestSingle);

Promise.all(arrayOfRequestPromises)
  .then(allResults => {
    // do something
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // handle errors
  });
```

But then you lose the maximum 3 concurrent requests option.

Comment: Thanks for MadaraUchiha, i will try on my side then let you know if it works well. Btw thank @jfriend00

Comment: Why do you have `array.requestSingle`?

Comment: @jfriend00 Typo, this is too early in the morning for me.

Comment: How do I implement following logic:

#1 after connecting to http://www.google.com1, fetch the html, then save to 1.html

after connecting to http://www.google.com2, fetch the html, then save to 2.html
...

#2 In my async.js code, i can set timeout before callback. In other word,  I will have some seconds' delay during each 3 items running. Can this be implemented here?

Thanks

Comment: @J.Lyu It can (and look good too!), but that's a bit broad for an answer on Stack Overflow, you should look into the Promise primitive, and how it abstracts asynchronous values. Promises are highly composable, you can wait for the first of N promises (implementing a timeout), and wait for the result of all promises (creating a waiting point for synchronization), you can use `.then()` to create chains of Promises, and you can do all those things together.

Comment: yes you are all right man.  Give me some minutes to understand all of those. Thanks for your help.

Comment: hi. I just tried following code (only shows the main part):

const requestSingle = number => setTimeout(function () {
    requestAsync(`${url}${number}`).
        then(response => {
            console.log(number + ' is running');
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err + ' - ERROR');
        })
}, 5000);

Promise.map(array, requestSingle, { concurrency: 3 });

The final output generated at the same time. Seems concurrency : 3 doesn't work.